# React Semantic UI Dropdown Search Selection not selected on click

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic-ui-react dropdown copied from their site. In their example everything works fine, but why when I copy the code to my project the options need to be double-clicked to get the value? Any clue for this?
I just copied this:

```
const countryOptions = [
  { key: 'af', value: 'af', flag: 'af', text: 'Afghanistan' },
  { key: 'ax', value: 'ax', flag: 'ax', text: 'Aland Islands' },
  { key: 'al', value: 'al', flag: 'al', text: 'Albania' },
  { key: 'dz', value: 'dz', flag: 'dz', text: 'Algeria' },
  { key: 'as', value: 'as', flag: 'as', text: 'American Samoa' },
  { key: 'ad', value: 'ad', flag: 'ad', text: 'Andorra' },
  { key: 'ao', value: 'ao', flag: 'ao', text: 'Angola' },
  { key: 'ai', value: 'ai', flag: 'ai', text: 'Anguilla' },
  { key: 'ag', value: 'ag', flag: 'ag', text: 'Antigua' },
  { key: 'ar', value: 'ar', flag: 'ar', text: 'Argentina' },
  { key: 'am', value: 'am', flag: 'am', text: 'Armenia' },
  { key: 'aw', value: 'aw', flag: 'aw', text: 'Aruba' },
  { key: 'au', value: 'au', flag: 'au', text: 'Australia' },
  { key: 'at', value: 'at', flag: 'at', text: 'Austria' },
  { key: 'az', value: 'az', flag: 'az', text: 'Azerbaijan' },
  { key: 'bs', value: 'bs', flag: 'bs', text: 'Bahamas' },
  { key: 'bh', value: 'bh', flag: 'bh', text: 'Bahrain' },
  { key: 'bd', value: 'bd', flag: 'bd', text: 'Bangladesh' },
  { key: 'bb', value: 'bb', flag: 'bb', text: 'Barbados' },
  { key: 'by', value: 'by', flag: 'by', text: 'Belarus' },
  { key: 'be', value: 'be', flag: 'be', text: 'Belgium' },
  { key: 'bz', value: 'bz', flag: 'bz', text: 'Belize' },
  { key: 'bj', value: 'bj', flag: 'bj', text: 'Benin' },
]
```

and inside my `render()`:

```
<Dropdown
    placeholder='Select Country'
    fluid
    search
    selection
    options={countryOptions}
/>
```

PS: keyboard navigation not working too

Comment: are u already add their theme "<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" />"

Comment: yes, off course @ronydavid

Comment: it is weird, I just tried it and everything just work fine, check my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-field-257tl

Comment: @ronydavid i also tried that approach but still not working, i don't know why it behave differently on my code.

Comment: is that all part of your code, if not, i think u need to show us the rest of your code